# Retornar a URL de uma imagem via JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Estou comunicando meu site com a [API do Behance](https://www.behance.net/dev) e tenho o seguinte script escrito em Angular 1.5.5:

```
var app = angular.module('PortfolioApp', []);

app.controller('PortfolioCtrl', function($scope, portfolioFactory) {

  portfolioFactory.getBehance()
  .then(function onFulfilled(data){
    $scope.projetos = data;
    $scope.behanceLoaded = true;
  })
  .catch(function onRejected() {
    console.log('Erro no Factory');
  });

});

app.factory('portfolioFactory', function($http) {  

  var getBehance = function() {
    var user = 'luandavi';
    var apiKey = 'APIKEY';
      return $http.jsonp('https://behance.net/v2/users/'+ user +'/projects?api_key='+ apiKey + '&callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
      .then(function onFulfilled(response) {
        return response.data.projects;
        console.log(response.data.projetcs);
    });
  };

  return { 
    getBehance: getBehance
  };

});
```

E ele aqui eu mostro eles

```
<body ng-app="PortfolioApp">

    <div ng-controller="PortfolioCtrl" class="grid">
        <div ng-repeat="projeto in projetos" class="item">
            <img src="{{projeto.covers.original}}">
            <h1>{{projeto.name}}</h1>
            <p>{{projeto.stats.views}}</p>
        </ul>
    </div>

<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

O problema é que este "original" é uma imagem com o tamanho original que foi enviado ao Behance, obviamente. Eu queria poder usar uma das thumbnails que a própria plataforma gera, depois que meu projeto foi ao ar. Das opções que o JSON retorna, exitem as seguintes:

```
"covers": {
        "115": "https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/projects/115/ebf44656341149.Y3JvcCwxMzg0LDEwODMsMzcsMA.jpg",
        "202": "https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/projects/202/ebf44656341149.Y3JvcCwxMzg0LDEwODMsMzcsMA.jpg",
        "230": "https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/projects/230/ebf44656341149.Y3JvcCwxMzg0LDEwODMsMzcsMA.jpg",
        "404": "https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/projects/404/ebf44656341149.Y3JvcCwxMzg0LDEwODMsMzcsMA.jpg",
        "original": "https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/projects/original/ebf44656341149.Y3JvcCwxMzg0LDEwODMsMzcsMA.jpg"
      },
```

Mas se eu usar esse número no projeto.cover.404 por exemplo, o angular acusa erro de sintaxe. O que eu posso fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altere o código:

```
<img  ng-src="{{projeto.covers[404]}}">
```

Referência: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc

Porque em javascript não é aceito propriedade de objeto numérica.

```js
var covers = {
        "115": "https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/projects/115/ebf44656341149.Y3JvcCwxMzg0LDEwODMsMzcsMA.jpg",
        "202": "https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/projects/202/ebf44656341149.Y3JvcCwxMzg0LDEwODMsMzcsMA.jpg",
        "230": "https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/projects/230/ebf44656341149.Y3JvcCwxMzg0LDEwODMsMzcsMA.jpg",
        "404": "https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/projects/404/ebf44656341149.Y3JvcCwxMzg0LDEwODMsMzcsMA.jpg",
        "original": "https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/projects/original/ebf44656341149.Y3JvcCwxMzg0LDEwODMsMzcsMA.jpg"
      }
      
 console.log(covers[404]);
```

Referência: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Comment: Valeu! Ele funcionou, porém o console retorna esse erro: 
GET http://localhost/luan.digital/%7B%7Bprojeto.covers[404]%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @LuanDavi utilize ng-src, editei a resposta dê uma olhada